# Do I have to implement my own matrix stack in a WP8 Direct3D application?

Tags: matrix, windows-phone-8, stack, directx, direct3d

I would like to use a matrix stack to keep track of transforms in a hierarchical model. Only bummer is, it appears that there is no built-in matrix stack class I can use to do this. The Direct3D templates simply keep track of a model, view, and projection matrix and then passes those to the vertex shader.

Renderer making the constant buffer:

```
CD3D11_BUFFER_DESC constantBufferDesc(sizeof(ModelViewProjectionConstantBuffer), D3D11_BIND_CONSTANT_BUFFER);
DX::ThrowIfFailed(
    m_d3dDevice->CreateBuffer(
    &constantBufferDesc,
    nullptr,
    &m_constantBuffer)
    );
```

Vertex Shader transforming each vertex:

```
cbuffer ModelViewProjectionConstantBuffer : register(b0)
{
    matrix model;
    matrix view;
    matrix projection;
};

...
// Transform the vertex position into projected space.
pos = mul(pos, model);
pos = mul(pos, view);
pos = mul(pos, projection);
output.pos = pos;
...
```

I have spent some time looking for a built in matrix stack class so that I wouldn't have to reinvent the wheel, but the only promising lead I got, [the ID3DXMatrixStack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb174038%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), doesn't appear to be accessible in a WP8 Direct3D app.

So am I missing something or do I need to write my own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to write your own. The ID3DXMatrixStack interface went out with Direct3D10.

Comment: All right, It shouldn't be hard but I was hoping to avoid the work. Thanks!